# Null pointer execption

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database, hibernate

i am facing null pointer exception in hibernate:

org.hibernate.dialect.function.CastFunction.render(CastFunction.java:11)

hibernate code is:
("Select  date_format(str_to_date(form.dobDate,'%Y%m%d'),'%M (%Y)') as Month");

Comment: every exception has two important features - a message and a stacktrace. You have omitted the 2nd. Also - what you pasted is a query, not 'hibernate code'.

Comment: It seems to me that dobDate is null, but as Bozho says: without the stacktrace it's really hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: there is stack trace.                   java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.hibernate.dialect.function.CastFunction.render(CastFunction.java:59)
 org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator.endFunctionTemplate(SqlGenerator.java:208)
 org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.methodCall(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2319)
 org.hibernate.hql.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.simpleExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:2691)

Comment: this is not the whole stacktrace. Edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info I would guess that dobDate is null (or the form).

However I feel yo are going against the grain here. I think hibernate's purpose is not to return properly formatted strings. I am already happy when hibernate translates my Java objects to/from the database properly.

Formatting dates etc I prefer to do in the Java code, actually as close as possible to the outside world, in the UI or in the I/O layers and keep things like dates as dates. This offers more flexibility and I find it keeps the code cleaner.

These kind of formatting things in hibernate are useful with legacy databases in where clauses though